# Resharper reference errors between .netcore / .netstandard projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, resharper

I've got two projects in Visual Studio, where classes in the first one refers to classes in the second. The first project is a .netcore app, with the following in it's project file:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

The second project has multiple target frameworks:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461;net462</TargetFrameworks>
```

Both projects compile and work fine, but classes located in the the second project appear red in code in the first project, as if there is a reference error. For context, here's a generic example:

[image]

The smudged out red part is a class defined in the other project. I can navigate to it (using <kbd>F12</kbd> / "go to definition" or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click), but when I hover the cursor above the red text, is says

> *Cannot resolve symbol 'MyClassName'*

So just to be absolutely clear: **Everything still works** - it's just that Resharper erroneously reports a reference error her, and that bugs me.

How do I know resharper is causing this? Because if I disable Resharper (*Tools -> Options, search for resharper and click "suspend"*), the error disappears:

[image]

Enabling Reshaper again causes the error to return immediately.

I suspect this has something to do with the types of projects (i.e. their target frameworks), but I haven't been able to figure it out exactly.

Any ideas about how get rid of these errors?

Comment: Sounds like a but. I'd suggest to search their issue tracker for similar bug and if not found - post an issue. I doubt people on this site can help with that. You can also install last EAP version of ReSharper and see if that is fixed there.

Comment: @Kjartan I've made a minimal example but couldn't reproduce your issues: https://github.com/matkoch/resharper-issue-2018-02-22-references

Comment: I am having this issue and I have tried everything to resolve it with no luck. This is very frustrating

Comment: I have the same problem in Visual Studio 2022 with Resharper 
JetBrains ReSharper 2023.3.3
  
Build 233.0.20240117.105338 built on 2024-01-17 Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.1

Answer (score 3):

Resharper shenanigans

**Solution 1**

```
Tools->Options->ReSharper
```

- Suspend Now
- Resume

It refreshes the cache and/or some other *dark magic*

---

**Solution 2**

You could try clearing the ReSharper cache implicitly

```
ReSharper->Options->Environment->General
```

- Clear Caches.

---

**Solution 3**

You can also try unloading and then reloading the project.

```
Solution Explorer->Right Click
```

- Unload Project
- Reload Project

---

**Solution 4**

As a last resort you can try to delete the solution cache manually

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVsXX\vXX\SolutionCaches\
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the ideas, but unfortunately they do not seem to fix anything. As soon as the projects are reloaded, the errors reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest ReSharper Version 2018.3.4

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet tool install JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools --version 2021.2.2
```